# codename one apps how to deal with the phone screen resolutions for my app components to adjust accordly

Tags: codenameone, screen-orientation

```
Student-ListForm-BGColor{
    background-color: #0052cc;
}

Student-List-SorterContainer{
    background-color: #0052cc;
    padding-bottom: 1.5mm;
}

Student-List-Infinit-Container{
    background-color:white;
}

Student-Name-Box{
    margin-top: 1mm;
    margin-bottom: 1.3mm;
}

Student-Name-Field{
    color: black;
    font-family: "native:MainRegular";
    font-size: 2.7mm;
}

Student-class-Field{
    color: #0052cc;
    font-family: "native:MainRegular";
    font-size: 2.3mm;
}
```

components in image one appear to be very big, is there a way to make it adjust accordingly 
Because am using CSS for all my Styles

Comment: are the element heights based on a percentage of the screen height?

Comment: no thats what am asking is it possible to do in codename one because am using CSS for styling

Comment: Use millimeters not percentages. They will look different in the simulator since the device density is different but on the device the size will look right because the screen density is higher. Include the CSS you used or at least the relevant parts for a more detailed answer

Comment: @ShaiAlmog am already using millimeters as i have added some of my CSS

Comment: What specifically looks bigger than what you defined? Did you measure this on a device? Which UIID isn't working and how does that specific size difference expressed? Did you use component inspector to understand the source of the size difference?